# Is it possible to use media sdk (NDK) introduced in lollipop into a project to run on Android 16 +

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to build a project using NDK media sdk, but I need it to run on older phones too (to support 90% of the market...). Now, I am able to include the libmediasdk.so & libOpenMAXAL.so manually, and it seem to link properly, but I am not sure this is a correct practice.
Moreover, the libraries (libmediasdk.so & libOpenMAXAL.so) are expected to be available on the target device, so unless I do copy them manually to the project/libs/arch-arm the application complains libraries are not found.

Have I gone too far ? :) hope not..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write code that optionally uses the new native media functions (libmediandk.so), but you can only use it on Android 21+. So if you want to support older android versions, you must make this codepath optional, allowing it to fail cleanly on other devices where libmediandk.so doesn't exist.

If the `MediaCodec` APIs are optional within your app and you are ok with them only being available on Android 21+, you can just make sure you build this into a separate lib (like libyourapp-media.so), and be ready to handle the case when `System.loadLibrary()` for this library fails.

However, if you want to use other native code components in your app, there's a few gotchas you need to know. If you build your app targeting `android-21` and your native code uses certain functions (such as `atof`), it will only run on `android-21` or newer (even if code using the function `atof` would build just fine for the older platforms). The reason for this is that the `atof` function didn't exist before, and calls to it were redirected to `strtod`. If you build your library targeting `android-21`, it will actually do the calls to `atof` instead, which doesn't exist in the older platform versions. This also goes for quite a number of other functions, not only `atof`. See http://b.android.com/73725 for details on this.

Therefore, if you want to use the new native media APIs in a library that should be loadable on older versions (except for the native media APIs that obviously won't work on older versions), you need to build your native components targeting an older android version. You'd need to duplicate the `media/*` headers from `android-21`, but instead of linking to `libmediandk.so` (`-lmediandk` in `LOCAL_LDLIBS`), you'd need to load this library at runtime using `dlopen`.

If you need to do the same on older platforms as well, you should use the `MediaCodec` API in java (which you can call via JNI). Then, there's little point in doing all of this extra work just to use the native version of the API on Android 21+, when you can use the java API on all versions (it works from Android 16, and more reliably since Android 18).

Comment: Yepp... what I thought! (can't vote up yet.. sorry!)